# how to set an objects string field to a jsf listbox

Tags: jsf

In JSF backing bean I have defined the value as,

```
private List<Cite> cites = new ArrayList<Cite>();
```

And `Cite` has a string like

```
Cite {
    private String value;
}
```

JSF code

```html
 <h:panelGroup>                 
    <h:outputText value="Cite"/>
    <h:inputText id="citeTxt" style="width:75px" value="#{manualDataEntryRegText.cite}">
       <f:ajax execute="@this" render="citeTxt" />
    </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>


<h:panelGroup>  
    <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{manualDataEntryRegText.editCite}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="dtCites" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>


<h:panelGroup>
    <h:selectManyListbox style="width:75px" id="dtCites" value="#{manualDataEntryRegText.cites}" var="cite" size="3">
        <c:selectItems id="citeSelectItems" value="#{cite.value}" />
        <c:ajax event="change" />
    </h:selectManyListbox>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: It would be better if you use the `f` letter instead of `c` for JSF Core tag components. This is because `c` is commonly used for JSTL code.

Comment: Also note that `<h:selectManyListbox>` tag doesn't have a `var` attribute, `<f:selectItems>` id attribute is senseless, as well as your usage of attributes is `<f:ajax>` is excessive.

Comment: what does it mean f:ajax is excessive ?

Comment: @Phoenix What he means is it's unnecessary to add `event="change"` to the ajax, as that's what it will default to in the case of `<h:selectManyListbox/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your list of as follows:

```
<h:selectManyListbox style="width:75px" id="dtCites" value="#{manualDataEntryRegText.cites}" size="3" converter="citeConverter" ...>
    <f:selectItems value="#{citeBean.allCites}" var="cite"
itemLabel="#{cite.value}" itemValue="#{cite}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

and don't forget to create and add a `@FacesConverter` for `Cite` class (basic example can be found in [Mkyong's tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)) *or* bind all the values (`value` of listbox and `itemValue` of select items) as plain strings.

Comment: `manualDataEntryRegText.cites` looks like a `List<Cite>` (based on OP content), I guess it should be `manualDataEntryRegText.city` when the attribute in managed bean is `City city`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I didn't get your point. OP deals with multiple selection here.

Comment: By the way, it would be great if you post the base code to define the `FacesConverter` as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So did I at the beginning :) I think, basing on excessively wrong attributes usage that OP *might have thought* like that as well. Regarding the converter code I don't feel like repeating the things many of us have already posted here. Let it be OP's personal investigations. What we'd rather do is to correct OP's tag usage.

Answer (score 0):

List should be a `SelectItem` list:

```
List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

SelectItem s  = new SelectItem(cite.value, "lable");
lilst.add(s)

 <f:selectItems id="citeSelectItems" value="#{bean.list}" />
```

Comment: OP is using JSF2, not JSF1. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info to learn more.