# How to implement foreach in jsf?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How do I create ofer_has_location objects (join object from location and ofer) using the current ofer and the selected items from the h:selectManyCheckBox

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="companyidCompany" 
    value="#{oferController.selected.companyidCompany}" 
    title="#{bundle.CreateOferTitle_companyidCompany}"
    required="true" 
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateOferRequiredMessage_companyidCompany}">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="companyidCompany"
        render="locationCollection" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{companyController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOferLabel_locationCollection}"
    for="locationCollection" />      
<h:selectManyListbox id="locationCollection" value="locations"
    title="#{bundle.CreateOferTitle_locationCollection}">                       
    <c:forEach items="locations">      
        <f:selectItems var="locations"
            value="#{oferController.selected.companyidCompany.locationCollection}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `<c:forEach>`. Just get rid of it, provide for converters, use the right value binding in listbox and prepare necessary data in AJAX listener method and that's it.

Comment: @skuntsel, you'll need to break all that down

Comment: @kolossus Then I'll leave OP without his personal experience which could have negative impact on his ability to write real world applications :)

Comment: @skuntsel could you please elavorate a bit more? Just how to implement de converter and which is the correct value binding, I'm kind of lost

Comment: Sure, I'll provide you with some guidance.

Comment: Here you go! Take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in order to achieve 'connected elements' functionality:

1. Have two elements ( `<h:selectOneMenu>` and `<h:selectManyLisBox>` in your case), where the second one will be dependent on the selected option(s) of the first one. The second element must have an id in order to be rerendered afterwards.
2. Every HTML `select` element (that's rendered by both JSF tags of your choice) will have a set of `option`s that are not supposed to be created via iterative element like `<c:forEach>` (though, it is in fact possible), but rather via the `<f:selectItem>`/`<f:selectItems>` tags (thus, remove your iterative tag in comment).
3. When values in the components are bound not as plain `String`s, or primitive wrappers (`Integer`, etc.), but rather as model objects (`YourClass` objects, etc.), then you need to tell JSF two things: how can it print `option`'s `value` from your class and how can it reconstruct an object from request parameter that is a string. For this you need to implement [Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html), that is, explain JSF how to do the abovementioned transformations. Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021966/1820286) and [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters) as reference points. Note the appropriate syntax for `<f:selectItems itemValue="...">` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092387/1820286).
4. Model values bound by these two components also need to represent your classes, just in a same way as selected items' values. For `<h:selectOneMenu>` it is `value="#{}"`; for `<h:selectManyListbox>` it is `value="#{}"` with `YourClass selectOneMenuValue` and `List<YourClass> selectManyListboxValues`  or `YourClass[] selectManyListboxValues` bean properties respectively.
5. Population of second `select` will be handled via `<f:ajax>` tag. As contents need to be calculated 'on the fly', the right spot to make it is within its `listener` attribute (i.e. to have `List<YourClass> contentsOfSecondListbox = createListboxValues(YourClass oneMenuSelectedOption);`) . As you'd desire to rerender the second element, specify its client id in `render` attribute of `<f:ajax>`. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176594/1820286).

In case you are binding, for example, to `String`/`String[]` values, you won't need the converter parts.

Try to go through it step by step to find out your errors and correct them.

Comment: I can not make it work yet, value in my custom converter getAsObject  method is returning "on" and I don't know why

Comment: Got it working!!!!!! thank you very much!!! jpa handeled the join table sweetly, it worked like a charm!!!! Thank you very much!!!!